# Drawing a figure of three wires, coupled at specific points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a three wire network(shown by three different colors), as shown below.
This is my MWE, but I am messing up some where, as my wires are coming on top of each other unlike what I want.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\newcommand\wire[5][]%
{\draw[#1]
    (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
    -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick,blue]{G-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,blue]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,blue]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,1}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
    }
    \draw[<->] ($(G-1-2)!0.5!(G-1-3)$) -- +(-0.5,0) node[midway,above]{$\theta_{2}$};
    \draw[<->] ($(G-1-2)!-0.5!(G-2-3)$) -- +(-0.5,0) node[midway, above]{$\theta_{1}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The third argument, `#3`, to `\wire` is supposed to give a tikz coordinate when used as `(#3)` but you are giving it things like `{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0`. In this case, you probably want `\i*\pairdist-\wiredist,0`. Once this is fixed you will of course need to adjust the values of `#4` and `#5` to get different shapes for your wires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you had in mind

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\newcommand\fwidth{0.7} % for the black wire
\pgfmathsetmacro\blockwidth{2 * \wirewidth + \fwidth * \wirewidth + 3 * \wiredist} % block size

\newcommand\mup[1]{-- ++ (90 : #1 * \wireheight)}
\newcommand\mright[1]{-- ++ (0 : #1 * \wirewidth)}
\newcommand\mleft[1]{-- ++ (180 : #1 * \wirewidth)}
% \wire[options]{name}{start}{width}
\newcommand\gwire[4][]{
  \draw[#1] (#3, 0) \mup{1} \mright{#4} \mup{1} \mleft{#4} \mup{2} \mright{#4} \mup{1} \mleft{#4} \mup{1} \mright{#4} \mup{1} coordinate (#2-1);
}
\newcommand\kwire[4][]{
  \draw[#1] (#3, 0) ++ (#4, 0) \mup{1} \mleft{#4} \mup{1.3} \mright{#4} \mup{1.7} \mleft{#4} \mup{1.2} \mright{#4} \mup{1.8} coordinate (#2-1);
}
\newcommand\bwire[4][]{
  \draw[#1] (#3, 0) \mup{2} \mright{#4} \mup{1} \mleft{#4} \mup{2} \mright{#4} \mup{1} \mleft{#4} \mup{1} coordinate (#2-1);
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]

  \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
  {
    \gwire[thick,green]{G-\i}{\i * \blockwidth}{1}
    \kwire[thick,black]{K-\i}{\i * \blockwidth + \wirewidth + \wiredist}{\fwidth}
    \bwire[thick,blue]{B-\i}{\i * \blockwidth + \wirewidth + \fwidth * \wirewidth + 2 * \wiredist}{1}
   }

   \draw[<->] (K-0-1) -- (B-0-1) node[above, midway]{$\theta_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Precisely, this is what I would like to get. Extremely thankful to you and for your time. Is there a way to write those $ \theta $(s)?

Comment: @Shamina Sure, you just need to add coordinates as you did in your example code

Comment: To move the theta_2 along y-axis, do I need to change the `(K-0-1) -- (B-0-1)` the `1` to the `y`-coordinate? Can you remind me these points, thanks? Seem to be forgetting. So that I will be able to do it by myself, without disturbing you further

Comment: @Shamina No, `1` in `(K-0-1)` is just a label that I added at the last point of the path. If you want labels for all corners you need to add them manually with `coordinate(#2-<label>)`, a simpler solution is just 

`\draw[<->] ($(K-0-1)+(0,-1)$) -- ($(B-0-1)+(0,-1)$) node[above, midway]{$\theta_1$};`